# Calling a controller function in javascript that will store an entry in a database using ajax (Laravel 4)

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, controller, laravel-4

I am trying to store an entry in a database after a click using an ajax call to a route that calls a controller function in javascript (in Laravel 4).

I have a resource "artists", that is controlled by an "ArtistsController".  The view where I am making the call is called "show.blade.php" in an "artists" directory (i.e. the page shows different artists: artists/1, artists/2, etc...).

I also have a table called "fanartists", where I want to store this data.  Basically, when a user clicks a button on a specific artist's page, I want the relationship to be stored in this table.

Here is the relevant code:

show.blade.php:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '*****************',
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true,
            oauth      : true
            //xfbml      : true  
    });


      $( '.opener' ).click(function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',

            link: 'http://crowdtest.dev:8888/artists/',
            name: 'Hello',
            caption: 'Hello',
            description: 'Hello!'

            });

            request = $.ajax({
        url: "/artists/fbclick",
        type: "post",
        data: serialised data
     });

      });
};
</script>

<a class="add-list-button-no-margin opener" style="color: white; font:14px / 14px 'DINMedium','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Play my city</a>
```

ArtistsController:

```
public function fbclick($id) {

        $artist = Artist::find($id);

        $fanartist = new Fanartist;
        $fanartist->artist_id = $artist->id; //the id of the current artist page (i.e. artists/1, id=1)
        $fanartist->fan_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $fanartist->save();

    }
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/artists/fbclick', array('uses' => 'ArtistsController@fbclick'));
```

When I include the ajax request, the FB feed does not pop up.  When I remove it, it does.  Also, it is not storing the data in the database like I want it to.

Do you see anything wrong here?  Your help is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you see any error? try to debug using web developer tools

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } [VM] 5 (1362):70 

I am not sure the file that this is referring to.

Comment: try writing your `click` event handler outside `window.fbAsyncInit` function.

Comment: But then I won't be able to have the FB.ui feed object pop up right?

Comment: it will check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrzXF/), since the api is not provided you may get wrong api error

Comment: hmm, I tried it on my project and the FB popup isn't coming up, nor is the fiddle working...

Comment: The error is gone after I added the brackets around the serialised data part, but now the FB popup isn't coming up

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33743/discussion-between-trying-tobemyself-rahul-and-user1072337)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some slight mistakes in your script.

In your ajax request you are using `post` as the method, but you have defined your route as `get` so either change your route to `post` or change ajax method to `get`. I will go with `post` route so your new route is `Route::post('/artists/fbclick', array('uses' => 'ArtistsController@fbclick')');`
And ajax data field should be in json format, so now you ajax request will look some what like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/artists/fbclick",
    type: "post",
    data: {field_name :'data'}
 });
```

Finally coming to you controller function, with silght changes

```
public function fbclick() {

    // $artist = Artist::find($id);
    $id=Input::get('field_name'); //field_name is the field name from your Json data  
    $fanartist = new Fanartist;
    $fanartist->artist_id = $id; //the id of the current artist page (i.e. artists/1, id=1)
    $fanartist->fan_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $fanartist->save();

}
```

Everything should work now